# how do typical chatting application like yahoo messenger implement chatting with different users?

Tags: java, sockets, chat

I have gone through resources on building chat application using socket programming in java. In every implementation people try to make a server which runs in infinite loop, accepting the connections from client and creating a separate thread for handling the chat.
I want to make a chat application in which a new dialog/chat window pops when someone wants to chat with me (on client side). But the catch is that i have only one socket through which i am connected to server. all the messages has to be sent through this streams, currently i am thinking of some adhoc approaches for directing output to different client windows but i am sure that there must be some elegant way to do this.

Comment: So, the server sends a message "someone wants to chat with you" using the socket which is connected with your client, the client app reads this message, and opens a window. Where's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a single socket connection per client, then all communication should be multiplex over that connection, which means that you need to develop a protocol on top of socket streams between your server and a client. A protocol is a set of rules. For example, clients may issue commands and server respond to them, like one command, one response. The commands and responses need to be marked and separated somehow from each other, perhaps you want to add an identifier and a length of a message and then refer to that message.

Various systems use different protocols.

Comment: thanks,designed a simple protocol in which each message has certain attributes which help client and server logic to direct it accordingly :)